# How to navigate in multi pages Web App with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angularjs-ng-click

I've a simple Web App with 2 html pages, see below :

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="ThirdCtrl">
    <h2> {{titre}}</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text"  ng-model="test"><br>
        <button  ng-click="toSend()">OK</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**indexv2.html**

```
 <div ng-controller="ThirdCtrl">
            <h2>{{titre}}</h2>
            {{test}}
 </div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ThirdCtrl', function($scope, $window){
    $scope.titre = "ThridCtrl";
    $scope.test = "";
    $scope.toSend= function()
    {
        $window.location.href = "http://localhost:10080/ClientAngular/indexv2.html";

    }
});
```

I'm trying to send data when button is clicked to an other page, redirection is working to **indexv2.html** but I can't to get my data "test". The data "titre" is weel displayed but not "test".

Do you know how can I to get a data after ng-click function ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you reload a new page, the angular application restarts from scratch, and everything you stored in memory is lost. Why don't you make a single-page app, and use a router?

Comment: @JBNizet  ok I'm going to do this Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to move data between pages - I had a similar situation which I'm still working on - just that he is not showing us enough code. Say you get a visitor's input data on a web form and need to display that data to another web page where you then send to a back-end server from the subsequent page, but all this using angularjs, how do you get that done?
Further you say get the value for 'titre' right on the subsequent page but not for 'test'. I think it is because 'test' has not been set - except otherwise you are not showing enough code.